# Using a negation in the sed command in UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I am new to shell, started learning it few days ago and I encountered a problem. I want to use the sed command in order to filter the files. 
First, I want to delete all files from the list that don't contain the word zad
So I do this :

```
ls | sed '/[^{zad}]/d'
```

I don't get why does this remove all the files from the list? Does it remove all files that do not contain z, a or d in their names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/[^{zad}]/d` removes every line that contains at least one character that is not one of `{zad}`. That probably is true for *every* line.

To remove lines that contain `zad`, use `/zad/d`.

```
$ cat in.txt 
foo
bar
zad
-- zad --
baz
$ sed '/zad/d' < in.txt
foo
bar
baz
```

If you want to print the lines containing `zad`, use:

```
$ sed -n '/zad/p' < in.txt 
zad
-- zad --
```

`-n` prints nothing, `p` prints a matching line.

Comment: My question is, how to use the negation on a whole string, so it will eliminate all files that don't have the word zad in their names.

Comment: I do understand everything that you wrote, thank you for it. But I want to delete all the files that don't contain the word zad. I want to do this using negation. So I want to somehow negate this statement sed '/zad/p' so it will be something like sed '/(negation)zad/d'.

Comment: Another way to say it: `sed '/zad/!d'`

Answer (score 8):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/zad/!d' file
```

or:

```
sed -n '/zad/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rm $( ls | sed '#n
/zad/!p' )
```

failed (error on) if there is a non empty folder not having zad in his name, so maybe use `-fr` but be carefull not to delete some important folder with this kind of command

Comment: always intersting to have a -1 without reason. is it so dummy as reply ? By thge way, this is the only reply to the full request and not just the sed part ...